# Registro duplo no banco de dados?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, pdo

Já revirei meu código e não achei o motivo que ele está adicionando dois registros no banco de dados.

Função:

```
public static function create($table, array $params) {
    $key = array_keys($params);
    $value = array_values($params);

    $key = "`" . implode("`, `", $key) . "`";
    $value = "'" . implode("', '", $value) . "'";

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `" . self::$_prefix . "{$table}` ({$key}) VALUES ({$value})";

    $pdo = self::get()->query($sql);
    $pdo->execute();
}
```

Chamada da função:

```
Connect::create('users', array(
    'name' => 'Guilherme',
    'lastname' => 'Alsdfafdves',
    'email' => 'gui@gmail.com',
    'username' => 'caraiosssss',
    'password' => '123456',
));
```

Comment: O `execute()` eu não sei se funciona, o `query()` já faz o insert

Comment: opa resolvido :)

Comment: Otimo! crie uma resposta com os detalhes de como resolveu :)

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi meu erro, já que a função `self::get()->query();` já faz o trabalho de executar, apenas removi o `$pdo->execute();`.

Comment: O `execute()` é para instruções preparadas(`prepare()`)